# How to remove files from git commit history?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, github

I've tried

```
git rm --cached
```

which didn't work, I've heard I could possibly do this using `git rm *` but there seems to be some batching issues with that.

I have AWS keys in my commit history that I'd like to remove ASAP.

If I could remove all of my git commit history and just push up the app in it's current form with no commit history that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the documentation.
 [Remove Sensitive Data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

Comment: I ran those commands but the AWS keys are still showing in the commit history and all 31 commits are still there as well. What am I doing wrong? See my workflow: https://gist.github.com/pblogs/d844c8e1a519b3484ecb Thanks!

Comment: You begin by specifying the correct file, are your keys in your Rakefile? lol
Keep reading and try the BFG cleaner if the above suggestion fails.